# Interfacing Ada enumerations and C enums

Tags: enums, ada, type-conversion

Let in C code are defined:

```
typedef enum { A=1, B=2 } option_type;

void f(option_type option);
```

Let we also have Ada code:

```
type Option_Type is (A, B);
for Option_Type'Size use Interfaces.C.int'Size;
for Option_Type use (A=>1, B=>2);

X: Option_Type := A;
```

Which of the following code is correct (accordingly RM)?

-- First code

```
declare
   procedure F (Option: Option_Type)
      with Import, Convention=>C, External_Name=>"f";
begin
   F(X);
end;
```

or

-- Second code

```
declare
   procedure F (Option: Interfaces.C.unsigned)
      with Import, Convention=>C, External_Name=>"f";
   function Conv is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(Option_Type, Interfaces.C.unsigned);
begin
   F(Conv(X));
end;
```

I think both first and second Ada fragments are correct but am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is 100% correct.

In C:

```
typedef enum { A=1, B=2 } option_type;
```

In Ada:

```
type Option_Type is (A, B);
for Option_Type'Size use Interfaces.C.int'Size;
for Option_Type use (A=>1, B=>2);
```

The Ada code assumes that the C type `option_type` has the same size as a C `int`. Your second snippet assumes it has the same representation as a C `unsigned int`.

Neither assumption is supported by the C standard.

Quoting the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft, section 6.7.2.2, paragraph 4:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with **`char`**, a signed
>   integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the enumeration.

So the C type `option_type` could be as narrow as 1 byte or as wide as the widest supported integer type (typically 8 bytes), and it could be either signed or unsigned. C restricts the values of the enumeration constants to the range of type `int`, but that doesn't imply that the type itself is compatible with `int` -- or with `unsigned int`.

If you have knowledge of the characteristics of the particular C compiler you're using (the phrase "implementation-defined" means that those characteristics must be documented), then you can rely on those characteristics -- but your code is going to be non-portable.

I'm not aware of any completely portable way to define an Ada type that's compatible with a given C enumeration type. (I've been away from Ada for a long time, so I could be missing something.)

The only portable approach I can think of is to write a C wrapper function that takes an argument of a specified integer type and calls `f()`. The conversion from the integer type to `option_type` is then handled by the C compiler, and the wrapper exposes a function with an argument of known type to Ada.

```
void f_wrapper(int option) {
    f(option); /* the conversion from int to option_type is implicit */
}
```

Comment: Ugh, It seems that C standard was changed! I remember that it was that representation of enum is the same as of `int` (or was it `unsigned int`?) I hope my memory do well, it is C standard that fails.

Comment: So I am going to use `with Convention=>C` with some Ada enumeration types. It would work at least with GNAT

Comment: The default representation of an `enum` is in C or C++ is `int`. Since C++11, you can define the type (I'm not sure which version of C allows that, if any.) Something like: `enum [class|struct] name [: unsigned] { ... };` See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: @AlexisWilke: C++ is unrelated!

Comment: @porton: No, the C standard has not significantly changed in this regard since the 1989 ANSI standard. An enumeration *constant* is of type `int`. An enumeration *type* is compatible with some implementation-defined integer type. For an enumeration type with a small number of values, a compiler might reasonably make it 1 byte.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: No, the default representation of an `enum` is not `int` in either C or C++, and the link you mentioned does not support your claim. C does not permit defining the type with which a given enumeration type is compatible.

Comment: @porton: Quite possibly `with Conversion => C` will work, as long as you use it to match an Ada enumeration type to a C enumeration type. (I haven't studied the Ada RM closely enough to be sure of that.) Just don't assume that a C enumeration type corresponds to any particular C integer type -- unless you're willing to accept non-portable code.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Convention, not Conversion

Comment: @KeithThompson, that is probably correct for C. In C++ it defaults to `int` if all the enumerator values fit in an `int`. The link I provided does mention that.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: My reading of the C++ standard is that that applies only to *scoped* enumeration types, defined with `enum class` or `enum struct` (which don't exist in C).

Comment: @AlexisWilke (6 years later) C++17 says "It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than **`int`** unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an **`int`** or **`unsigned int`**." C++11 has similar wording (probably identical, I haven't checked).